# Recommended method for error handling in Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm interested in what the recommended way for handling errors may be in Spring Cloud Dataflow, specifically for consuming off of dead letter queues.

Say you have a stream like so:

```
http | transform --some-expression | log
```

In the event you receive messages that result in errors in the transform, sending messages to a DLQ that you define, how would you then reprocess them? How would you define the DLQ?

Since the DLQ would live on the RabbitMQ instance that Dataflow uses, creating a `rabbit` source with url/user/password seems cumbersome as Dataflow already knows those values.

I was thinking the only possible way would be to have another stream that reads the DLQ:

```
rabbit --host=<dataflow rabbit host> --queues=<dlq> ... | transform --new-expression | log
```

Is there a better pattern in Dataflow? And does it differ with Kafka?

Comment: You are right. The DLQ has to be processed separately as part of a different stream.

Comment: That's too bad @sobychacko there doesn't seem to be very good error handling methods or docs about dealing with it in dataflow. Becomes difficult to track events as they go through the stream and a headache if they fail at different points in a stream